# Can I have a For-loop in php to display the "rows" in a database?

Tags: php, sql

I have registered members and I want to display their names and profile pictures in a ordered list. I just wanted to know if I can use a sort of a for-loop to display all the users in the rows of the database table?

I had this as an idea to work with:

```
$sql    = "SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY `user_name` ASC";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($user = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        for (i = 0; i <= mysql_num_rows; i++){
            echo $user['user_name'] . '<a href="#"> ADD TO FRIENDS</a><br/><br/>';
            echo '<img width="50" height="50" src="avatars/' . $user['pic_location'] .'">';
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that what your while loop is already doing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please consider doing a little searching before posting questions to SO. There are A LOT of learning resources out there.

For example, here's a PHP tutorial on how to access data in databases:
http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql/4

Answer (score 4):

Just remove the `for(?)` loop. What you want to do is already done by the `while`.